# How can I store data into database? (One to One Relationship Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have two model 
Company:

```
public function slug(){
    return $this->hasOne(Slug::class);
}
```

and Slug:

```
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

Slug table :

```
Schema::create('slugs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
        $table->string('slug');
    });
```

How can I store data into Slug table ?
I want store company id into company_id column and str_slug() of company name into slug column

Comment: What did you tried so far? Have you consulted the documentation? Its pretty good described there.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to add a slug to a company with Id of 1.

This should help!

```
$company = App\Company::find(1);
$company->slug()->save(new App\Slug([$data]));
```

Comment: No, I want store data into Slug table in Company store method, so when I create company then I want to store Company name into Slug table

Comment: This will do so.
Or you can simply write, App\Slug::create($data)
After creating the complany.

Comment: If you create company using create method that should return a Company model.

Eg. $new = App\Company::create($data);

Now you can access new company id like $new->id

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need separated table for this. You will always have 1 value which probably will not change (due to SEO). But...
You can use observers https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers
On created() method in your observer you can make it like that:

```
public function created(Company $company){
   \App\Slug::create(['company_id' => $company->id, 'slug' => str_slug($company->name)]);
}
```

The same can be done if your slug is in company's table as field. Just use create() method instead and $company->slug = str_slug($company->name). And you can forget about them.